# Proper way to find out the reason for comment deletion

Tags: support, feature-request

My comment got deleted - not a big deal. But I am just slightly curious about the exact flag used because I would like to post it again with hopefully less of what was deemed unacceptable.

As suggested by most answers to similar questions I tried to use the [contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) link first. It was the 1st time I ever used it so I am unaware of the expected turn-around times. It's only been couple of days. Should have I waited more before bringing it to meta?

As for the `feature-request` part, I believe it would have been nice to be able to have access to history of all own actions including deleted comments as well. But I think similar proposals have been denied before. Probably because of the magnitude of development effort required to implement the changes.

So I would like to propose another (much easier to implement) way to give the authors a heads up - just send them a message with the reason for the deletion (and probably the original text as well) when the deletion is approved.

Comment: So the "heads up" might look something like this? "Your comment 'Why didn't you read the manual? This is a basic question.' was deleted for the following reason: 'Not constructive' . "

Comment: @RobertColumbia, something like that. Maybe add a link to the post the deleted comment was intended for as well.

Answer (score 6):

I disagree with this feature request.

The more active you are on the site the more you'd find notifications that a comment has been deleted for reason X to be pointless. I really do not care if three years after the fact one of my comments was deleted for being "obsolete" or "too chatty". Even "not constructive" is probably not going to be *that* useful to know. You'd have to carefully narrow your proposal here to have the beginning of a useful feature.

Moreover, flags on comments are supposed to have a moderating effect. When someone has been rude and their comment has *just* been deleted, it seems to me that telling them the comment has been deleted for being rude may just prompt them to post a new rude comment. Moderators already warn and suspend repeat offenders but I'd rather the rude commenter not know about the deletion and perhaps have time to calm down rather than get a notification.

I'd also expect that if people start getting notified with every comment deletion, we'll have users complain about it. We already have people complain about declined flags even when it is blindingly clear that the flag was not legitimate, so you can bet we'll also get people ticked off that their comment was deleted for a reason they do not agree with.

Answer (score 6):

There is a really simple way to evaluate why one of your comments might have been deleted.

1. Was the purpose of your comment anything other than to clarify something specific about the content of a post, or to ask for such clarification?
2. Was your comment incorporated into the post, so that the comment is no longer needed?

An affirmative answer to either one of these questions subjects your comment to removal.

Comments are intended to be temporary anyway.  I'm not sure that bugging SE corporate about why a comment was deleted is a good use of anyone's time.

Comment: I completely agree that using *contact us* form for this purpose is a waste of time. That's why I am suggesting this feature. As for the purpose of my deleted comment - a few weeks back I came across a question which I knew for a fact did not have a solution. I provided a detailed answer explaining  why the desired solution was not possible. My answer was refused by the OP who claimed that he was making a steady progress toward his goal. So couple of days ago I remembered about it and posted the comment merely asking if the OP is still making any progress.

Comment: Which question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39639931/1778421

Comment: Ah, yeah.  The reason for deleting that comment should already be obvious.

Comment: I do not care if the OP would change his mind. I was just hoping he would admit his being wrong for the sake of other people who might find his question later on and take his claims seriously based on the number of upvotes it got. He chose to flag my comment instead.

Comment: For the record I did not want anyone to close the question, specially not for being *too broad*. I was hoping for the unlikely event of the author eventually updating his post with his latest findings. Closing the thread just killed that (albeit remote) possibility.